# Cplex: Sum all k less than t

Tags: cplex

In cplex how do I represent this,

\sum_k<=t, for all t.

So t is given, which in cplex I'd write:

forall(t in T)

and the range of k is such that for all k<= t.

Answer (score 1):

you could write

```
range T=1..4;
dvar int x[T];
subject to 
{
forall(t in T) sum(k in T:k<=t) k==x[t];
}
```

regards

Comment: Thanks. But what does this part mean?  k==x[t]

Comment: Hi, x[t] should be equal to the sum. This was just a small example to show you how slicing works. Do not hesitate to try that small example.